# Pytorch - Are gradients transferred on creation of new Variables?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have the following code:

```
A = Tensor of [186,3]
```

If I create a new empty tensor as follows:

```
tempTens = torch.tensor(np.zeros((186,3)), requires_grad = True).cuda()
```

And I apply some operations on a block of A and output it into tempTens, which I use totally for further computation, say like this:

```
tempTens[20,:] = SomeMatrix * A[20,:]
```

Will the gradients actually be transferred correctly, lets say I am having a cost function that optimizes for the output of tempTens to some ground truth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, `tempTens[20,:] = SomeMatrix * A[20,:]` is an in-place operation with respect to `tempTens`, which is generally not guaranteed to work with autograd. However, if you create a new variable by applying an operation like [concatenation](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.cat)

```
output = torch.cat([SomeMatrix * A[20, :], torch.zeros(163, 3, device='cuda')], dim=0)
```

you will get the same result in terms of math (a matrix with first 20 rows from `SomeMatrix * A[20, :]` and the following 166 rows of 0s), but this will work properly with autograd. This is, generally speaking, the right way to approach this kind of problems.

Comment: Hmm..the reason is because I need to "update" in variables into tempTens which are dependant on each other. So I might do tempTens[20,:] * tempTens[40:60,:] etc. I suppose this is not possible, and ill have to split them into seperate vars